# How to delete an email from Outlook using C#?

Tags: c#, email, outlook, outlook-2007

I can successfully retrieve and read emails from Outlook using the following code. How can I delete an email from Outlook? I have tried several ways but couldn't get it to work.

```cs
var svc = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
svc.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
svc.AutodiscoverUrl(emailAddress);
EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.Bind(svc, emailMessage.Id, props);
```

Comment: What are the ways you've tried?  What are the errors (or behaviour) that you're seeing?

Comment: Another question is how do you know if you successfully deleted an email. You are basically talking to exchange server. So not all communication results can be seen in outlook. Deleting an email is one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure (ie, may be proven incorrect) that you can *delete* messages using this API.  The [MSDN article for Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Transport.Email Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa563872%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) says this:

> The Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Transport.Email namespace contains types that support creating, reading, writing, and modifying e-mail message.

And further inspection of the members available on the `EmailMessage` class suggest you can access various properties, but there's no "delete" operation/method available.

Depending on your scenario, you might have better luck using a tool like Outlook Redemption which will allow low-level programmatic access to Outlook and/or Exchange (but may not be appropriate if you need to go via exchange web services).

Comment: finally figure it out!
Just simply using this syntax:

    emailMessage.Delete(DeleteMode.MoveToDeletedItems);

Thankss

Comment: @user1647773 Thanks for the accept... but for usefulness of this question/answer for other users in future, would you mind clarifying if the syntax you're referring to is `Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Transport.Email` or Outlook Redemption?